# Imitar comportamiento de slideToggle() [de jQuery] con React

Tags: jquery, css3, reactjs

Estoy intentando implementar con react un comportamiento similar para un menú desplegable como el que proporciona `slideToggle()` de jQuery. Por ejemplo cuando se presiona el botón del menu:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con jQuery es muy sencillo:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.menu-icon').on('click', function(){
        $('nav').slideToggle();
    })
})
```

Suponiendo que el código HTML es el siguiente:

```
<header>
  <div class="menu">
    <div class="contenedor">
      <p class="logo">Fitness Gym Home</p>
      <img src="imagenes/menu.png" class="menu-icon" alt="">
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Pricing</a></li>
          <li><a href="">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Si quisiera replicar un comportamiento similar pero con el siguiente componente en react:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './header.css';

class Header extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <header>
                <div className='menu'>
                    <div className='contenedor'>
                        <p className='logo'>Fitness Gym Home</p>
                        <img 
                            src={require("../../assets/menu.png")} 
                            className="menu-icon" 
                        />
                        <nav>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Pricing</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">About</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </nav>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </header>
        );
    }
}

export default Header;
```

de que manera se puede lograr?
He hecho algunas pruebas en las cuales según una propiedad del `state` del componente que cambia de `true` a `false` y viceversa al hacer click sobre el icono del menú asigna o quita una clase css que muestra o no el `<nav>`. Pero no logro el comportamiento del slide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voy a tomar los conceptos de este [post de @DanPrince en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33979921/react-using-jquery-to-slidetoggle) para responder

El contexto de `this` en `React` no es el `elemento` es el `Componente de React` `jQuery` no interpreta como usarlo como selector

En tal sentido, se necesitará referenciar al elemento que deseas controlar con `jQuery`.

```js
// JSX

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.element = 'menu-toggle'
    this.toggleButton = this.toggleButton.bind(this)
  }
  
  toggleButton() {
    $(this.refs[this.element]).slideToggle()
  }

  render() {
    return (
    
    <div>
        <button onClick={this.toggleButton}>Burger Button</button>
        <div ref={this.element}>
          <header>
                <br />
                <div className='menu'>
                    <div className='contenedor'>
                        <p className='logo'>Fitness Gym Home</p>
                        <img 
                            src="https://www.fillmurray.com/200/100"
                            className="menu-icon" 
                        />
                        <nav>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Pricing</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">About</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </nav>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </header>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```css
/** CSS */

body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

li {
  margin: 8px 0;
  font-size:12px;
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->

<body>
  <div id="app"></div>
</body>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

El [this.refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#the-ref-callback-attribute) toma un `callback`, el cual se ejecutará cuando el componente este desplegado (`mounted`)

No obstante en la misma documentación de `React` señalada previamente, se sugiere en la medida de la posible evitar manipular el Dom directamente... como estas usando `node` hay varios paquetes por ahí que se pueden instalar para conseguir lo antes expuesto, es cuestión de probar y ver cual se ajusta más a tus necesidades.

Comment: Excelente, muchas gracias por tu respuesta.